# Quietly install MONO using dockerfile

Tags: docker

I am exploring docker. I want to create an image from Ubuntu with Mono installed on it. I created a Dockerfile as follows: -

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER abc@xyz.com
ENV http_proxy "http://abc:xyz@myproxyserver:3128"
ENV https_proxy "https://abc:xyz@myproxyserver:3128"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y mono-complete
CMD["echo","Latest Ubuntu with MONO"]
```

On building the above Dockerfile it got stuck at the configuration of the timezone data. How can I pass the default timezone option in the dockerfile itself.

Also one more question 
Can I create an image by merging two different images. I mean to say that we have one docker image for latest ubuntu and another docker image for latest mono. Can I combine both these images and have latest ubuntu with latest mono.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Try this in your dockerfile:

```
ENV TZ=Europe/Rome
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
```

List of timezone is here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

2) Personally I have never met such a requirement, so I am not sure these [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds) fit for you. Take a look.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. Can you please give some hint on my second question. 
 Can I create an image by merging two different images. I want an image with latest ubuntu with latest mono installed on it.

Comment: If the answer solved, you could mark it as correct (the green check image under the arrows).